# Add date to SQL table

Tags: sql, date, presto

Presto SQL

The idea is to get the historic data from the table by querying date. How to add current_date (YYYY-MM-DD) data I will set a refresh on daily. So when I want to look back of 5 days data I get the info.

**Data type **
member_id bigint
segemnt_id integer

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ABC;
CREATE TABLE ABC AS ( SELECT member_id, Segment_id FROM XYZ)
```

**This XYZ table has information of member_id and segment_id** (Creating a separate table since XYZ contains many column just to reduce the load)

```
CREATE TABLE QQQ
(member_id bigint,
segment_id int)

INSERT INTO QQQ
(SELECT*, current_date as date, member_id, segment_id FROM ABC);
```

Comment: Hi, it’s not clear, to me, what you are asking. Do you just want to add a date column to the table and, if so, what issue are you facing when you tried this?